# AFrame physical system bounding box of <a-box> is too large, compare to a-box actual size

Tags: three.js, size, physics, aframe, bounding-box

I'm making wall around my circular table object to prevent user go through it.
Using `aframe`, `aframe-extras`.

And when I turn on `physic="debug:true"`, as I can see the sizes of bounding boxes are not correct.

Please see my screenshot bellow (Sorry I don't have enough reps to inline the image).

[Screenshot of wrong bounding boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkeMe.jpg)

So the question is: **Why I got that issue and how can I correct it ?**

Comment: You might have better luck with `static-body="shape: box"` or `static-body="shape: cylinder"`. If not, I'd recommend opening a bug on the aframe-physics-system repository in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, I already set `"shape: box"` because you said that it have greatest performance. Hm, May be I'll open an issue.